# How can i add missing values of a multidimensional associative array to an HTML table using PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays

I'm attempting to print an array to html table in php and am having issues where the array elements differ in number (eg. missing fields).

How can I solve the problem where sometimes one (or more) header elements are missing from the array, so the values end up under the wrong header?

Here's my code. I think I need to add another loop to make sure all of the $rows line up with the $keys...?

Input Array:

```
array (size=16)
 0=>
  'created_by' => string 'me@example.com' (length=31)
  'bug_status' => string 'verified' (length=8)
  'reported_by' => string 'me@example.com' (length=31)
  'modified_ts' => string '1413503800000' (length=13)
  'bug_id' => string '123' (length=3)
  'bug_severity' => string 'normal' (length=6)
  'product' => string 'core graveyard' (length=14)
  'bug_version_num' => string '9' (length=1)
  'assigned_to' => string 'me@example.com' (length=19)
  'op_sys' => string 'windows nt' (length=10)
  '_id' => string '123.1217503800000' (length=17)
  'component' => string 'viewer app' (length=10)
  'modified_by' => string 'nobody@example.org' (length=18)
  'priority' => string 'p2' (length=2)
  'qa_contact' => string '#unknown' (length=8)
  'created_ts' => string '901720800000' (length=12)
```

Here's my PHP code:

```
$keys = array_keys($array[0]);
echo "<table><tr><th>".implode("</th><th>", $keys)."</th></tr>";
foreach ($array as $rows) {
  if (!is_array($rows))
    continue;
  echo "<tr><td>".implode("</td><td>", $rows )."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>
```

Comment: I did not do a -1 but what output do you get when you run this?

Comment: what does the input array look like?

Comment: Turn this into a question to avoid downvotes. SO policy.

Comment: it puts out HTML, but the values in the rows don't line up w/ the headers always since that array has missing elements.

Comment: dont use implode, use a loop based on the 'full' count, deal with the blanks in the loop

Comment: updated w/ example input array. My full result set has thousands of these, with some missing elements in the array.

Comment: `array_pad($input, 16, "");`

Comment: @BenSullins Did I express your question correctly? If not, please modify.

Comment: @BernhardPoiss, the manual would disagree ("If pad_size is positive then the array is padded on the right, if it's negative then on the left")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create your table and headers for you and then insert values only if that key exists.  I'm sure it can be improved but worked fine with the sample data.

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'a' => '1',
        'b' => '2',
        'c' => '3'
    ),
    array(
        'a' => '1',
        'b' => '2',
        'd' => '4',
        'e' => '5'
    )
);

$headers = array();
$thead = "<thead>";
foreach($array as $innerArray) {
    foreach($innerArray as $key => $value) {
        if (!in_array($key, $headers)) {
            $thead .= "<th>" . $key . "</th>";
            $headers[] = $key;
        }
    }
}
$thead .= "</thead>";

$tbody = "<tbody>";
foreach($array as $innerArray) {
    $tbody .= "<tr>";
    foreach($headers as $th) {
        $tbody .= "<td>";
        if (isset($innerArray[$th])) {
            $tbody .= $innerArray[$th];
        }
        $tbody .= "</td>";
    }
    $tbody .= "</tr>";
}

$table = "<table>" . $thead . $tbody . "</table>";

echo $table;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

```
$keys = array_keys($array[0]);
echo '<table><tr><th>'.implode('</th><th>', $keys).'</th></tr>';

foreach ($array as $row){
    if (!is_array($row)) continue;

    //Go through each of the keys you need and set them to empty if they're not set
    foreach($keys as $keyName){
        if (!isset($row[$keyName])  $row[$keyName] = '';
    }

    echo '<tr><td>'.implode("</td><td>", $row ).'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Alternatively, you can use `empty()`, `is_null()`, or other checks instead of `!isset()`, depending on what you're expecting/testing for.

Comment: this looks good, just one issue, what if the first array does not contain all of the fields? Is there a way to find the array w/ the most keys and use that to generate the header and $keys array?